# Ember model hasMany not working

Tags: ember.js

I'm running into an issue with some very simple Ember setup. I have two separate models, `appointment` and `item`. My `appointment` model has a property, `appointmentBins`, which `hasMany('item')`. However, the array is always coming back empty and I have no idea why. Here are the relevant models:

```
// appointment model
let attr = DS.attr;

export default DS.Model.extend({
  // ...
  appointmentBins: DS.hasMany('item'),
  confirmed: attr('boolean'),
  specialInstructions: attr('string'),
  // ...
}); 


// item model
let attr = DS.attr;

export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: attr('string'),
  userComments: attr('string'),
  internalComments: attr('string'),
  // ...
});
```

And here's the `appointment` serializer that I'm using:

```
export default DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  isNewSerializerAPI: true,
  attrs: {
    appointmentBins: { serialize: 'ids', deserializer: 'records'},
    // ...
  }
});
```

And finally, here's the response from the network call:

```
appointment: {
  appointment_bins: [,…]
    0: {id: 27, title: "", user_comments: null, internal_comments: null, user_id: 23, item_category_id: 10,…}
    1: {id: 28, title: "", user_comments: null, internal_comments: null, user_id: 23, item_category_id: 10,…}
    2: {id: 29, title: "", user_comments: null, internal_comments: null, user_id: 23, item_category_id: 10,…}
    3: {id: 30, title: "", user_comments: null, internal_comments: null, user_id: 23, item_category_id: 10,…}
  confirmed: false
  id: "f2eb7da8b2b31f2ebad0"
  special_instructions: ""
  // ...
}
```

I have no idea what I'm missing - this doesn't seem to be anything particularly complex, but I just can't parse the returned array inside the appointments model. Help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `deserialize`, not `deserializer` http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html